# Pulling out latest (multiple) entries from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to retrieve information on how many attempts a user takes to solve a particular problem as a JSON from a mongodb database. If there are multiple attempts on the same problem, I would only like to pull out the last entry - for instance, right now, if I do a db.proficiencies.find() - I will pull out entries A, B, C, and D but I would like to only pull out entries B and D (latest entries for the problems maze and circle respectively).

Is there an easy way to do so?

```
Entry A
{
    "problem": "maze",
    "courseLesson": "elementary_one, 1",
    "studentId": "51ed51d0fcb4cc3696000001",
    "studentName": "Sarah",
    "_id": "51ed51defcb4cc3696000011",
    "__v": 0,
    "date": "2013-07-22T15:38:06.259Z",
    "numberOfAttemptsBeforeSolved": 1
  }

Entry B
{
    "problem": "maze",
    "courseLesson": "elementary_one, 1",
    "studentId": "51ed51d0fcb4cc3696000001",
    "studentName": "Sarah",
    "_id": "51ed51defcb4cc3696000011",
    "__v": 0,
    "date": "2013-07-27T15:38:06.259Z",
    "numberOfAttemptsBeforeSolved": 1
  }

Entry C
{
    "problem": "circle",
    "courseLesson": "elementary_one, 1",
    "studentId": "51ed51d0fcb4cc3696000001",
    "studentName": "Sarah",
    "_id": "51ed51defcb4cc3696000011",
    "__v": 0,
    "date": "2013-07-22T15:38:06.259Z",
    "numberOfAttemptsBeforeSolved": 2
  }

Entry D
{
    "problem": "circle",
    "courseLesson": "elementary_one, 1",
    "studentId": "51ed51d0fcb4cc3696000001",
    "studentName": "Sarah",
    "_id": "51ed51defcb4cc3696000011",
    "__v": 0,
    "date": "2013-07-27T15:38:06.259Z",
    "numberOfAttemptsBeforeSolved": 4
  }


var ProficiencySchema = new Schema({

  problem: String
  , numberOfAttemptsBeforeSolved: {type: Number, default: 0}
  //refers to which lesson, e.g. elementary_one, 2 refers to lesson 2 of elementary_one
  , courseLesson: String
  , date: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
  , studentId: Schema.Types.ObjectId
  , studentName: String
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to sort the results in descending date-time order (so the latest response is first) and then to limit the result set by one. This would look something like:

```
db.proficiencies.find(YOUR QUERY).sort({'date': -1}).limit(1)
```